# Create entities using webhook in dialogflow without using dialogflow UI

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, webhooks, entities

Is it possible to create entities using webhook instead of dialogflow UI

I have an intent which shows the menu list`[pizza, burger, combo]` and when someone select an option `[suppose pizza]` then it will show list of pizza `[pepperoni, country special, farmhouse]`

currently I have created below entities using dialogflow UI

```
@menu [pizza, burger, combo]
@pizza [pepperoni, country special, farmhouse]
@burger [veg, ham, cheese]
@combo
```

But I want to manage all this entities from my backend, without creating it in the dialogflow

If someone changes the pizzaTypes in the backend then it should auto populate in the dialogflow

Is it possible to do that? and if possible then how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Dialogflow API for this. https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2-overview

They have some client libraries as well. Keep in mind that it can get quite complex to do this programmatically but it is possible nonetheless. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Follow the documentation...create entity type by HTTP request

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.entityTypes/create